# How can i add new button in checkout shipping step near Next Button in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, checkout, admin, frontend

How can i add new button in checkout shipping step near next button as show in screenshot
also need to call controller when button click

[image]

can any one help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html** in your theme.
Then open the file and check the **next** button. Add the following code:

```
<div class="primary">
    <button type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
        <span translate="'New Button'" />
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i call custom controller on submit this new button

Comment: Do you need to call custom controller on click of new button?